# Avoid including path to BOOST into exe

Tags: c++, boost

We are working on a project written in C++ using BOOST, and the project is being built in Visual Studio. Inspecting the project build (exe file) I've discovered there is an entry of path to BOOST (on a build server). So, I guess it's there due to the `__FILE__` macro.

**EDIT**: It's Release configuration with no debug information.

**EDIT2**: The following command is used for building BOOST:

```
b2 --toolset=msvc-10.0 --stagedir=./stage/2010/win32
address-model=32 variant=release
threading=single,multi link=static
runtime-link=static debug-symbols=off
```

Our customer doesn't want the path being there, so how to avoid absolute path including?

Regards,

Comment: build without debug information, or sanitize the paths (so that it's not there in the first place). Try using relative paths

Comment: > "Our customer doesn't want the path being there" - what reason do they cite? Is that reaon valid according to your supplier agreement?

Comment: @sehe No reasons, but customer always comes first. We use Release configuration for building both BOOST and our project.

Comment: So, indeed try to prevent the specific paths in the first place (and replace the customer)

Comment: may be you should avoid the parameter /fc during compilation?
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/027c4t2s.aspx

Comment: Well, you could always make another step in your build procedure that locates the offending path(s) in your binary(s) and writes X's over them. As long as it's just a string used to print something and not used to load code or files from the server, it ought to work fine. Just make sure the length doesn't change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use BOOST_EXCEPTION_DISABLE preprocessor definition